# inspect local vars in fork?

Tags: remix, hardhat, contract-debugging, local-variables

Trying to find a way to inspect local variables during method call when having failed tx.
Is there a way to example fork mainnet with hardhat and then to have insight on used local variables when calling contract method? something what remix has like debugger for call. Or can remix be integrated to be used with hardhat